# How the Kotlin compiler finds objects in a file

Tags: java, kotlin

Is JVM unable to detect variables (in the same scope) below a variable?

I.e., they can only detect variables declared before that variable.

I'm just trying to gain an understanding of how the compiler finds objects in a file (and it's limitations):

**kotlin code**

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    var first: Int = second + 2 // Unresolved Reference: Second 
    var second: Int = 1
    var third: Int = 1 + returnTwo() // works fine
}
fun returnTwo(): Int = 2
```

So the compiler moves from top to bottom - however it can retrieve a function object from anywhere?

Comment: It goes from top to bottom in a tree-ish way. Everything in the outer scope is available to inner scopes (hence `returnTwo` is available inside `main`), everything declared before a statement is available to that statement in the same scope. The first assertion is true  for classes/methods, not for conditional blocks/loops.

Comment: Note that the jvm is not the compiler as such.

Comment: The compiler doesn't find objects at all, let alone in a file. It compiles source code. In this case the Kotlin compller has failed to find a forward reference in one case but has succeeded in another., which suggests a compiler bug, or possibly that the Kotlin  language is under-specified. The Java compller doesn't have this limitation.

Comment: @user207421 what limitation are you referring to? Java doesn't "find" local variables that haven't been declared yet either.

Comment: ideone.com/QAzr6z - this throws a compiler error

Comment: Thanks. @BackSlash is there a page/keyword i can search to read more about this?

Answer (score 0):

Language like Java go from top to bottom i.e. line-by-line in a method scope. 
The Java compiler actually goes line-by-line converting the source code you have written in a specific method to an intermediate form called **byte-code** which the JVM uses to interpret and run on machines. 

Note that JAVA also creates a graph to resolve forward-dependency, like to check whether the output of a function call in variable assignment is correct or not or does it requires to an up-casting etc.

Whereas languages like Javascript have a concept called 'variable hoisting', where all the variables declared are automatically brought at top for rest of the functions to consume.

Comment: Java does not compile top to bottom or line by line. It is capable of handling forward references and indeed rather complex declaration graphs.

Comment: It *prints* a compiler error, in this specific case, but declaring a member class or function or variable after its first use does not, which is a counterexample to your assertion, which is therefore false.

Comment: Yes. JAVA creates this graph for methods and not for variables. I am only referencing to varaibles here i.e. why the comparison to javascript and its feature 'variable-hoisting'

Comment: Just to clarify the terminology used here: by "variables" swayamraina means local variables while @user207421 means fields. Hence the apparent disagreement, but you are talking about two different things and you are both right given your individual meanings.

Comment: You also appear to be wrong about Kotlin. Otherwise how did the OP's function call compile? You cannot possibly create a graph by going line by line. Obviously there is a special-case rule for local variables.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Obviously *not*. He is making a very specific claim about line by line compilation that is self-evidently untrue.

Comment: @user207421 he said "line by line **in a method scope**" which is kind of true. (It's not strictly line by line, since lines and spaces and form feeds and all other whitespace are all treated exactly the same by the Java compiler; nothing special about lines. Maybe he meant statement by statement.) Outside of a method scope, it's not line by line, but he never said it was.

Comment: so, by line-by-line is something to do with human readability. for a machine, line-by-line would mean statement-by-statement i.e. for java it would be any delimiter it uses to skip to a new-line.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException That isn't true either, otherwise no forward references would work, and they do; and there is certainly no 'line by line' about it. There is no evidence here of any understanding of how compilers really work.

Comment: @swayamraina No, it would be the semicolon. You don't even have to put any kind of space after a statement. E.g. the single line `int a=1;int b=c;int c=2;` would fail because c is not visible in the declaration of b.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of variables and methods is mandated by [section 6.3 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3). A Java compiler must comply with those rules, irrespective of how it is implemented. It doesn't matter if it scans the file top-down, bottom-up or sideways as long as it complies with the spec in regards to the scoping rules.

In the code sample you gave in your question, Kotlin scoping rules are very similar to those of Java; i.e. local variables are visible *after* declaration, and functions in global scope are visible everywhere.